# Cannot fetch static files from S3 via CloudFront CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to fetch GET a JSON static file which is in my public folder on cloudfront/S3. It works no problem on my local development environment where my files are stored locally, but on AWS I cannot fetch it; it returns my index html instead. Also if I paste the URL into my browser it takes me to the login, instead of displaying the json, like it does on my local environment. How do I retrieve the JSON static file?

Comment: Are you sure you have the CloudFront URL correct? Have you tried invalidating the CloudFront cache?

Comment: Yes I've created an invalidation on the whole bucket and the URL is indeed correct.

Comment: what is content type field s3

Comment: @KushVyas The content-type field is text/html in the response header even though I am sending content-type application/json in the request header, and the buckets CORS policy includes <AllowedHeader>Content-Type</AllowedHeader>

Comment: Are you using only the default(*) path behaviour in Cloudfront or do you have a custom set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the CloudFront setup I was using requires various cookies to be sent in every request in order to GET static content. These cookies were being saved in document.cookie but fetch does not include cookies by default, unless you pass the credentials: 'include' option.